# How to render seaborn objects repeatedly?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

The version of python I am using is 3.7. I tried it both in `Spyder` and `JupyterNotebook`

I used a `sns.dataset` as an example.

As I run the following code, the figure will be automatically rendered in IPython console without using `plt.show()` which is different from some instructions in previous posts.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()
df = sns.load_dataset('iris')
g = sns.pairplot(df, hue = 'species', height = 2.5)
```

However, I want to repeatedly show the seaborn object. How can I render `g`?
I've tried

```py
plt.show(g)
g.show()
```

etc...
but none of them works. I do not want that everytime I call a figure, I have to re-plot it.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you put the previously created `figure` object as the last line of new cells, this figure will return with whatever new additional elements, see cell 4 below:

[image]

In your case if `g = ...` is in your 1st cell, add an `f = plt.gcf()` to get the Figure object [as here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.gcf.html).